# Assign elements of a list to variables without knowing the size of list?

Tags: python

Say you want to assign the elements of a list to variables without knowing beforehand the size of the list, how do you do it, specifically in Python?

For example `lst` has 5 elements, program creates 5 variables (`var1`, `var2`, `var3`, `var4`, `var5`) and assigns the elements to it.

Comment: you should read the python tutorial: http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html
in python there is no need to know the length of a list in order to add elements to it

Comment: And what would you do with those variables if you don't know how many there are?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe you shoulde use `dict`

```
>>> lst = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> d = {}
>>> for i, item in enumerate(lst):
...     d['var' + str(i)] = item
... 
>>> d
{'var4': 4, 'var1': 1, 'var0': 0, 'var3': 3, 'var2': 2}
```

Answer (score 2):

If what you're asking is in effect - I want to have a list of 0-n elements, but I'm only going to know the values of elements, 5, 20, and 67, and everything else should be some default, then you can use a `dict` with an integer key as a sparse list.

```
d = {}
d[5] = 34.7
d[20] = 68.1
d[67] = 9.13
```

Then, you can use as:

```
d.get(5, 'default')
# 34.7
d.get(6, 'default')
# default
```

If you wanted to *materialise* that dictionary into a list then you can use a list-comp:

```
mylist = [d.get(i, 'default') for i in range(max(d))]
print len(mylist), mylist[:10]
# 67 ['default', 'default', 'default', 'default', 'default', 34.700000000000003, 'default', 'default', 'default', 'default']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just create an empty list and add any number of elements to it, without worrying about size.

```
mylist = [] #empty list, list is not constrained to be any particular size

mylist.append(some_var) #add a variable to list
```

Answer (score 0):

My answer is built on black_dragon's answer. My method for processing the list is his answer.

Since you want to create variables based on the values in the list you can use [globals()](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#globals), a built-in function for getting the global symbol table, to update the global dictionary. Updating the global symbol dictionary will create or modify the variables.

```
l = [10, 20, 30]

d = {}
for i,v in enumerate(l):
    d ['var'+str(i)] = v

globals().update(d)

print var0
print var1
print var2
```